# how to close new tab or new window (IE 6) on click of hyperlink

Tags: jquery, jsp

In my application when i click on menu option it open new tab in FF and new window in IE6, so my requirement is when i click on hyperlink on new open window it close new tab or new window(IE6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.close` ([MDC link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.close), [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Provided it's in direct response to a user-initiated action and the window was opened via script, it should close the window.

**Update**: Re your question below:

> I want to add onclick event following syntax `<a id="logout" href="<c:url value='/' />">Logout</a>` how should i modify this line for onclick event.

You have multiple options:

1. Use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol in the `href`:

   ```
   <a id="logout" href="javascript:window.close();">Logout</a>
   ```
2. Use an `onclick` attribute:

   ```
   <a id="logout" href="#" onclick="window.close(); return false;">Logout</a>
   ```
3. Hook up your event handler unobtrusively via script:

   ```
   <a id="logout" href="#">Logout</a>
   <!-- Elsewhere, probably in a script file you include at the very end
        of the body tag -->
   <script>
   document.getElementById("logout").onclick = function() {
       window.close();
       return false;
   };
   </script>
   ```

Comment: @ T.J . thanks for reply. I want to add onclick event following syntax  <a id="logout" href="<c:url value='/' />">Logout</a> how should i modify this line for onclick event

Comment: @amit: I've updated the answer to give you some options on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.close();` from Javascript to close the current window.

Comment: @ mads . thanks for reply. I want to add onclick event following syntax <a id="logout" href="<c:url value='/' />">Logout</a> how should i modify this line for onclick event